# Apple watch showing old notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-watch

On my apple watch I receive a imessage, I twist my wrist to show the message but for it always shows me the old messages and then the new imessage? How can I stop this so it either just shows me the new message or the actual up to date thread?

Comment: What makes the thread "up to date"? Are you comparing on the iPhone or do you want a different time ordering on the watch itself?

Comment: @bmike - comparing to my iphone. I've definately had a lot of message on my iwatch that are newer that the old one that always appear when I look at the incoming message. When I open the message app on the watch the thread is up to date, So I'm unsure why when a message comes in and i flick my wrist to read it that it has a quite old message on there, then the actual new message

Comment: My assumption is you need to dismiss each message on the watch (or clear them all) and the glance isn't removing it from the queue. Hard to guess that from where I sit, though

Comment: @bmike yeah I can appreciate that. There is nothing in my notifications however and I don't have messages in my glances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a watchOS 2 Bug**

The issue as described is basically that old, previously read/dismissed messages in a conversation continue to show up when new messages arrive (zombie messages) long after they were initially received and were marked as read.

The fix [described here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29704549#message29704549) is to delete the offending conversation on Apple Watch. Once this has been done, notifications for conversations with that contact will begin to function normally.

Doing this will not delete the conversation from any other device so you don't have to worry about losing your conversation, so even though it seems destructive, this is a non-destructive fix in that sense.

Note: the next time a notification for that same contact is received by the watch, the deleted conversation will be restored and viewable from the watch. Prior to that the conversation will not be present within the watch's Messages app's conversations list.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may not know that the configurations of your Apple Watch push notification system is different from your iPhone. The phone may receive the latest messages while the watch is lagging or doesn't receive any at all. Additional help can be found in the article "[How to Fix Apple Watch not Showing Notifications](https://web.archive.org/web/20160715092659/http://www.cupertinowatch.com/fix-apple-watch-not-showing-notifications/)" (Note: the original site is no longer working this link points to an archive site)